# Eslint Inheritance around Extends Property

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

We have a repo filled with apps linting in all sorts of different directions.  We've updated the linting for most of the apps to consolidate and want to take advantage of eslint inheritance/merging of properties, but the order of the `extends` property is important. How does merging work with `extends`?

We have a root .eslintrc that has a setup for typescript, which is the majority of our codebase, but in some of the child .eslintrc files we need to change the order of `extends` to include eslint for `vue` and the order is important so we've been added `root: true` to prevent inheritance.

Our root .eslintrc is a basic typescript setup that's used for some apps and all our APIs:

```js
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "jest"],
  "rules": {
    // ... removed for brevity
  },
  "overrides": [
    // ... removed for brevity
  ]
}
```

There are a couple Vue 2.x applications in the repo that have almost identical .eslintrc files except for the `extends` property which contains `plugin:vue/essential` between `eslint:recommended` and `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`.

Reading the docs and using `--print-config` can't figure out whether `extends` overwrites or tries to merge, or whether it's possible to have it override to include `plugin:vue/essential` at the right index:

```js
{
  // Added to prevent inheritance, but want to remove since other than a few
  // rules and overrides all the .eslintrc files are almost the same now
  // outside the requirement of `plugin:vue/essential`
  "root": true, 
  "globals": {
    "_": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    "node": true
  },
  // ------------------
  // How does `extends` property merge, or does it overwrite?
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  // ------------------
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue", "@typescript-eslint", "jest"],
  "rules": {
    // ... removed for brevity
  },
  "overrides": [
    // ... removed for brevity
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      // ... removed for brevity
    }
  }
}
```

If not we'll just keep them as separate files with `root: true`, and live with the duplication.